# How do I create a panel dataset out of transition date data in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a dataset that is structured as follows:

```
ID   origin   destination  time
1     a        b           2
2     b        a           1
2     a        c           4
3     c        b           1
3     b        c           3
```

I would like to turn this into a ID-time panel dataset like:

```
ID   location  time
1     a        1
1     b        2
1     b        3
1     b        4
2     a        1
2     a        2
2     a        3
2     c        4
3     b        1
3     b        2
3     c        3
3     c        4
```

So basically, I need to create the panel rows for when a subject doesn't change location, and fill in the location they are supposed to be at based on the info on origin and destinations. Is there any function in R that can do this smoothly? I'd prefer solutions using data.table or dplyr.

Comment: you could check out `zoo::na.locf`.

Comment: You are throwing out, eg, the info that ID 2 was at b initially?

Comment: @Frank No. I wouldn't like to throw it out. It is just a poorly thought off example data from my part.

Comment: The input example seems quite difficult to work with. For example, are we supposed to assume that if there isn't an observation at time = 1 they start at `a`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make a table with every `time` for which you want to know the `location` of each `ID`:

```
newDT = DT[, CJ(ID = unique(ID), time = 1:4)]
```

Then put the original data in long format, inferring that

- origin holds for `time-1`
- destination holds for `time`

```
mDT = melt(DT, id = c("ID", "time"), value.name = "loc", variable.name = "loc_role")
mDT[loc_role == "origin", time := time - 1L]
mDT[, loc_role := NULL]
setorder(mDT, ID, time)

    ID time loc
 1:  1    1   a
 2:  1    2   b
 3:  2    0   b
 4:  2    1   a
 5:  2    3   a
 6:  2    4   c
 7:  3    0   c
 8:  3    1   b
 9:  3    2   b
10:  3    3   c
```

...and fill in the new table with a rolling update join:

```
newDT[, location := mDT[.SD, on=.(ID, time), roll=TRUE, x.loc]]

    ID time location
 1:  1    1        a
 2:  1    2        b
 3:  1    3        b
 4:  1    4        b
 5:  2    1        a
 6:  2    2        a
 7:  2    3        a
 8:  2    4        c
 9:  3    1        b
10:  3    2        b
11:  3    3        c
12:  3    4        c
```

(Dplyr doesn't have rolling or update joins yet, so I guess there's no analogue.)

*How it works*

- `CJ` takes the Cartesian product of some vectors, similar to `expand.grid`
- `melt` transforms to long form, keeping variables passed as `id =`
- `x[i, v := expr]` edits column `v` of table `x` on rows selected by `i`
- `setorder` sorts in place
- `.SD` in `j` of `x[i,j]` refers to the subset of data (`x`) selected by `i`
- `x[i, on=, roll=, expr]` is a rolling join, with rows selected by table `i`, `on=` and `roll=`
- The expression `x.v` inside a join selects column `v` from `x`

Regarding the last bullet, the prefix `i.*` would do the same thing for columns from `i`.

Answer (score 3):

A similar method to Frank's solution, but using two joins would be:

```
library(data.table)
res <- setDT(expand.grid(ID = unique(dt$ID), time = 1:4))

#Get origin
res[dt[,.(ID, origin, time = time - 1L)], location := origin, on = .(ID = ID, time = time)]

#Update origin and destination
res[dt, location := destination, on = c("ID", "time")][, location := zoo::na.locf(location), by = ID][order(ID, time)]

 #   ID time location
 #1:  1    1        a
 #2:  1    2        b
 #3:  1    3        b
 #4:  1    4        b
 #5:  2    1        a
 #6:  2    2        a
 #7:  2    3        a
 #8:  2    4        c
 #9:  3    1        b
#10:  3    2        b
#11:  3    3        c
#12:  3    4        c
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need to do fancy joins for this problem:

```
maxt = max(dt$time)
dt[, .(location = c(rep(origin[1], time[1] - 1), rep(destination, diff(c(time, maxt + 1)))),
       time = 1:maxt), by = ID]
#    ID location time
# 1:  1        a    1
# 2:  1        b    2
# 3:  1        b    3
# 4:  1        b    4
# 5:  2        a    1
# 6:  2        a    2
# 7:  2        a    3
# 8:  2        c    4
# 9:  3        b    1
#10:  3        b    2
#11:  3        c    3
#12:  3        c    4
```

I've assumed that within a single ID next origin is the same as previous destination, as per the OP example.